# How call multi js function in one wasm function? with text format

Tags: webassembly

```
  var importObject = {
        funcs: {
            echo: arg => document.write(arg),
            log: console.log
        }
    };
```

I want to call both 'echo' and 'log' in one wasm function.

How can i code with text format?

Answer (score 0):

```
(module
  (import "funcs" "echo" (func $echo (result i32)))
  (import "funcs" "log" (func $log (result i32)))
  (table 0 anyfunc)
  (memory $0 1)
  (export "memory" (memory $0))
  (export "main" (func $main))
  (func $main (result i32)
    (drop
      (call $echo)
    )
    (drop
      (call $log)
    )
    (i32.const 1)
  )
)
```

The mainly is

`(drop (call $echo))
(drop (call $echo))`